# Disadvantages between a) filtering off a function through functions.php and b) remove the function call in it's location (Wordpress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

A scenario as example: when calling a function through shortcode so it displays in the post content, and it displays/ is being called also and still in it's default location - where we don't need it anymore - (as it happens with the comment_form and the comments_template functions), are there disadvantages between
a) filtering it off in the functions.php or
b) removing the function call from the default location

Both options in the child-theme, of course.

Comment: What file is the function currently in?

Comment: @mevius Where it is being called? comments.php (which is the comments template) is calling the comment_form() and single.php is calling the comments_template().

Comment: No, what I mean is...where are those two functions defined? Not where they're called.

Comment: The comments_template is defined in comments.php

Comment: The comments_template is defined in comments.php of the theme folder.
The comment_form seems to be defined in the comment-template.php inside the wp-includes folder. @mevius